# Shell commands: loading multiple values for variable from file

Tags: shell

I have to run the following command:

```
sudo trac-admin /var/www/trac/kpi wiki remove *
```

* Doesn't work, so I need change it with actual wiki names.

I have wiki names saved in a file, every name on new line.

I would like to feed contents of file as variable per single line to the original command trac-admin. How do I do this?

command that helped me delete all wikis in trac was:

```
for x in `cat trac.kpi.wiki2`; do sudo trac-admin /var/www/trac/kpi wiki remove $x; done
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use backticks `:

```
tmp]$ cat a.txt
foo
bar
baz
tmp]$ for x in `cat a.txt`; do echo $x; done
foo
bar
baz
tmp]$
```

Comment: for x in `cat trac.kpi.wiki2`; do sudo trac-admin /var/www/trac/kpi wiki remove $x; done

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether I understand your question correctly but maybe try:

```
cat /var/www/trac/kpi | xargs sudo trac-admin wiki remove
```

Comment: +1. `xargs` is the right command to use. Removed an inappropriate option.

Comment: This is not what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  sudo trac-admin /var/www/trac/kpi wiki remove $IFS;
done < /file/with/wiki/names
```

Comment: `while IFS= read -r line; do ...; done < filename` is a better way to read lines. Using a for-loop like this actually reads *words* from the file. In many cases there is only one word per line,  but not always.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot more sense! Thanks - I'll edit my answer.